# Can I "merge" my minecraft worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to ask if there is a way to merge multiple worlds into one. I want to combine my nether, end and overworld maps together

Comment: What version are you playing in? and do you just want to move a specific building from a world in to another or is it the whole nether?

Comment: I suspect this will need to be done through mods or a pre-built world of a set size, as it requires a world generation change.

Comment: It's certainly *possible*, but the question is whether someone's made a program that lets you do the thing you want to do. And I don't understand what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using structure blocks, they will save the structure as an NBT file, which you can put into other words.

## Limits

Java is limited to a 48x48x48 space, so this might not be too practical as so many structures would be required to do this, assuming you have a fairly large area you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can do it.

But you can install Minecraft mod, which will allow you to copy different objects (For example: a House) and transfer them into a new world or paste it somewhere else in the same world.